# ImageIO.read() not working after project moved from one computer to another

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I recently moved one project from my dying laptop to a healthy desktop computer. Changing no code or maven dependencies, ImageIO.read() is suddenly throwing an exception I've never seen before:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:66)
at finalProduct.ColorScales.<init>(Unknown Source)
at finalProduct.ColorScales.main(Unknown Source)
```

The project build compliance was set to Java 1.5 post-import. Could this have anything to do with the problem?

Edit: showing relevant code:

```
public class ColorScales extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3157452024224477459L;

public ColorScales() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(800, 700);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Program Color Scales");
    try {
        this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new MostRecentData().getClass().getResource("res\\programicon4.png")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setVisible(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
}}
```

The error is in fact at the line reading "this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(...));".

Comment: You seem to have a dependency requirement on [TwelveMonkeys JPEG SPI](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys), which isn't installed on your other computer

Comment: How should I proceed in fixing this issue? Where should I put the repository once downloaded?

Comment: One or more dependencies are registering the SPI, but failing to provide the actual implementation.  This could be direct dependencies in your project or in-direct dependencies which have been installed into the JRE

Comment: There's something odd going on with your class loader here, as the `META-INF/services` entries for the JPEG plugin is contained in the same JAR as the SPI class... Could it be that you upgraded to a different version of Java? Do you install a custom class loader somewhere? Have you switched from class path to modules recently?